# getting vue child component target of parent component event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dom-events

I am experimenting with Vue.js and I have a parent component with some child components. What I want to be able to do is track the components that get "click and dragged" over.

[This is an example to understand my problem.](https://codesandbox.io/s/ppyk144jk0)

So far what I have is the user initiates a `mousedown` event on the parent component which conditionally activates the `mouseover` listeners on the child components where I keep track of which child components get moved over. When the user releases the mouse button the `mouseover` listeners are removed.

I have been able to do this using this [method to conditionally add event listeners](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7349#issuecomment-380431978) the problem is when the initial `mousedown` event fires, the child component underneath doesn't trigger a `mouseover` event so it doesn't get tracked, subsequent `mouseover`s over child components are tracked as expected. I also want to be able to track the child component the mouse was over when it started the "click and drag".

To resolve this, I am getting the `event.target.__vue__` of the `mousedown` event to access the child component and call the tracking method explicitly. (Line 25 of App.vue in the example)

My question is: is there a more Vue.js appropriate way to trigger the tracking method on the child component which is underneath the initial `mousedown` that occurs on the parent other than using `event.target.__vue__`? Or generally is there a better way to track which child components get "click and dragged" over?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to do `startTracking` on the main app div instead of registering it on each child component, or from within the child component?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I think it uses less memory. If I register it on the parent there is only one listener vs having a mousedown listener on every child component.

Comment: You’re not going to have 1000s of child components, are you? I think that optimisation is a bit premature.

Comment: You can use an event bus and dispatch an event on it (which will be handled by the subscribed child components) inside your `mouseover` handler in the parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parent component and child copmonent exists strong relationship (like child component must be placed inside parent component), probably you'd like to try [Vue provide&inject](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject):

1. parent component provides one method to allow the children to register their tracks, then uses `provide` to pass it (below demo pass the instance by `this` keyword) to the children.
2. each child component just need to call that method to upload its tracks to the parent.

But for provide/inject, pay your attention on this:

> Note: the provide and inject bindings are NOT reactive. This is
> intentional. However, if you pass down an observed object, properties
> on that object do remain reactive.

Below is **one simple demo**:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('so-parent', {
  provide() {
    return {
      _tracker: this
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div @mousedown="toggleTrack(true)" @mouseup="toggleTrack(false)"><h3>children count: {{children.length}} - tracking: {{trackState}}</h3><h3>{{tracks}}</h3><slot></slot></div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      children: [],
      tracks: [],
      trackState: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    _registerChild(child) {
      this.children.push(child)
    },
    _registerTracks(track) {
      if (this.trackState) this.tracks.push(track)
    },
    toggleTrack: function(state) {
      this.trackState = state
      if(!this.trackState) {
        this.tracks = []
      }
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('so-child', {
  inject: {
    _tracker: {
      default () {
        console.error('so-child must be child of so-parent')
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      childState: false,
      childSeq: 0
    }
  },
  props: ['cid'],
  render(h) {
    return h('div', {
      class: 'child',
      on: {
        mouseover: () => this._tracker._registerTracks(this.cid)
      }
    }, [this.childSeq + ' Child Component ' + this.cid, this.$slots.default])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.childSeq = this._tracker.children.length
    this._tracker._registerChild(this)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
div.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  margin: 0 0.5em 1em;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  &:hover {
    background: #b2bde3;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <so-parent>
    <so-child cid="A"></so-child>
    <so-child cid="B"></so-child>
    <so-child cid="C"></so-child>
    <so-child cid="D"></so-child>
  </so-parent>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good solution to what I'm trying to do. Do you think it's better to inject references to the parent into all the child components or to just use the __vue__ object on the DOM element for this one scenario? is it wrong to use __vue__ or is it just a matter of code style?

Comment: `event.target.__vue__` is an internal variable to save Vue component instance by Vue framework, Vue team may not guaranty it will not be removed, even removed, it may not appeal at the user guide, and in your codes, the children of `div#app` may contains non Vue components, so `event.target.__vue__` may be undefined like mouse over `<p>`. So for my opinion, if we can find one solution with pure Vue API instead of some hacky way, that will be better.